# Finding trigonometric integral (challenging)

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Integrate:

> $$\displaystyle\int \dfrac{(1+\cos^2A\times\cos(2A))^2}{\cos(2A)\times(2\cos^4A+\sin^2A)}dA$$

Again my working with trigonometric identities has not take me anywhere useful, that is I haven't been able to break free of fractions or nasty products. But again, I'm a beginner to calculus and I only know how to integrate the 6 primary trigonometric functions. Perhaps there is a good way to bypass the tedious mess?

Despite the most off-putting look, the teacher claims that the integral is not anywhere as nasty as one would expect. This, of course, is not a part of class work but a challenge she threw at us.

Thanks in advance and as usual, all advice welcome.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: I think the question is like this :$ \frac{(1+cos^2A*cos(2A))^2}{cos(2A)*(2cos^4A+sin^2A)}dA$ Please confirm @Yun Fei Yang

Comment: The identity $\cos(2A) = 2\cos^2(A) - 1$ should come in  handy here.

Answer (score 2):

Keep working with the trig identities! In this particular example, it might help to turn everything into powers of $\cos A$. You'll get some nice cancellations.

When you're done canceling, you should have some trig functions that will be easier to integrate.

Comment: +1. "Keep working with the trig identities!" Indeed ... Sometimes, the hardest part of Calculus is Pre-Calculus.

Answer (score 2):

$ \frac{(1+cos^2A*cos(2A))^2}{cos(2A)*(2cos^4A+sin^2A)]}dA$ which after some simplification of the denominator part $(2cos^4A+sin^2A)$ gives the numerator part which is : $(1+cos^2A*cos(2A))^2$

Therefore after simplification  original problem = $\frac{(1+cos^2Acos(2A))}{cos(2A)}$
=$\frac{sin^2A + cos^2A +cos^2A(1-2sin^2A)}{cos2A} $

=$\frac{sin^2A(1-2cos^2A)+2cos^2A}{cos2A}$

=$\frac{-sin^2A(cos2A) +2cos^2A}{cos2A}$

=$ -sin^2A +\frac{2(1-sin^2A)}{cos2A}$

=$-sin^2A + 2sec2A -\frac{2-2sin^2A)}{cos2A}$

=$-sin^2A + 2sec2A -2sec2A +\frac{1-cos2A}{cos2A}$

= $-sin^2A +sec2A -1$

This you can can easily integrate.

Comment: It should be $+1$ instead of $-1$ in the last formula.

Comment: No its correct..@user64494

Comment: Substitute $A=0$ in the integrand and in the last formula.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $1/2\tan(A)/(\tan(A)^2+1)-1/2\ln(\tan(A)-1)+1/2\ln(\tan(A)+1)+1/2A.$

Comment: This simplifies a bit (and the $\TeX$ could use a little polish) ... and there's a letter of the alphabet missing.

Comment: @Blue: I think you mean $+C.$

Comment: That's the letter! :)